# How to make the variable chnage?

Tags: mit-scratch

Please help me with this my variable (Score) is not changing when i hit the enemy.
Programming: Scatch MIT

link for file
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/840044224

I expect it to change when i hit the enemy with bulet

Answer (score 3):

The `forever` loops that are supposed to increase score, are both under a `when green flag clicked` hat block.
That means they only work for the main instance of their sprite; not for clones.

[image: Original scoring loop]

Both the bullets and the enemies are clones; the main instances of the sprites are invisible and do not move.
That means the `touching` block will never detect a collision.

One solution is to replace the `when green flag clicked` hat block by a `when I start as a clone` hat block.

[image]

Another possibility is to remove the entire loop, and simply increase the score as you delete the enemy clone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the costume 2 sprite, put an `if` statement, if the costume 2 touches costume 3, increase the score by 1 as seen here:

[image: screenshot]

You can see [a modified version of the game](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/840751975/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a when clicked green flag block

Then add a forever block underneath

Then add if block in the forever block

In the <> in the if block go add a if touching red costume

Add a block change score by 1 in the if block